# Swift URLSession returns incorrect amount of bytes on request

Tags: swift, webkit, nsurlsession, urlsession

I have a url session requesting data by URL. The issue is the data retrieved by the url on a fresh app open is not proper.

**Problem:**

For example I delete the app and re-download the app and make a request by URL (1st time):

- Status Code: 200
- Bytes: 6365 bytes
- no metadata

The second time I make the url request:

- Status Code: 200
- Bytes: 1044440 bytes
- Metadata is valid and retreived

Example url:

> https://youtu.be/iogcY_4xGjo

**Description:**

The only time I have this issue is when I delete the app and make this request the first time. After the first request all other request are fine and work as normal using the same function.

This issue only happens when I delete that app to test as a first time user.

```
import Foundation
import Kanna
import WebKit

public extension URL {
    
    struct ValidationQueue {
        static var queue = OperationQueue()
    }
    
    func fetchPageInfo(_ completion: @escaping ((_ title: String?, _ description: String?, _ previewImage: String?) -> Void), failure: @escaping ((_ errorMessage: String) -> Void)) {
        
       
        var request = URLRequest(url: self)
        
        let newUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2)  AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4"
     
        
        request.setValue(newUserAgent, forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                   // print(error)
                    failure("Url receive no response")
                })
                return
            }
            
            if let urlResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                if urlResponse.statusCode >= 200 && urlResponse.statusCode < 400 {
                    print("Satus code: \(urlResponse.statusCode)")
                    if let data = data {
                        
                        print("data: \(data)")
                        
                        if let doc = try? Kanna.HTML(html: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                            let title = doc.title
                            var description: String? = nil
                            var previewImage: String? = nil
                            
                            
                            if let nodes = doc.head?.xpath("//meta").enumerated() {
                                print("nodes: \(nodes)")
                                for node in nodes {
                                    if node.element["property"]?.contains("description") == true ||
                                        node.element["name"] == "description" {
                                        description = node.element["content"]
                                    }
                                    
                                    if node.element["property"]?.contains("image") == true &&
                                        node.element["content"]?.contains("http") == true {
                                        previewImage = node.element["content"]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            
                            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                                print("t: \(title) \n d: \(description) \n i: \(previewImage)")
                                completion(title, description, previewImage)
                            })
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        failure("Url received \(urlResponse.statusCode) response")
                    })
                    return
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the data? I mean the string not its description.